# Angular inject a module after a function starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, inject

Ok, first question so.. be kind..

I am making this Angular Autofill input with Angular's Material framework.

I need to fill it with data that come from an ajax call. (i.e. a countries arrey) 
My initial approach was to have the module injected in the app's controller and then when the ajax call returns success I would just fire it's function.

That doesnt work well because it loads once (from the injection) before data are back and crashes on the check.

Take two: Adding a check for empty data caused it to load and stop as expected, then when the data come (eventually) the module cuts them in individual items and is ready but the page wont work. By wont work I mean it wont automatically suggest as you type..

I thought that I need to have the module loaded rather than the function inside it but I cant seem to do this.. That's what I need help with..

Adding the code:

```
angular.module("Myapp", ['ngMaterial', 'Autofill-country' ])
 .controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {

    //automatic suggest
     automaticsuggest ()
  function automaticsuggest() {
    suggesturl = 'http://www.mysuggest_front_services'
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: suggesturl,
        responseType: "json",
        async: false // Just tried that to see if it works.. I am not really fond of it 
    }).then(function (response) {
        countriesarrey = response.data.Countries

        // .run('Autofill-country', ['Autofill-country']) - Tried this too..
        country(); // this is the function of the autosuggest. 
Once checked with breakpoints it does get the array and cut it and filter it etc, but the n when you input something in the input field.. It doesnt suggest..            
    });

  }
```

And the autocomplete module

```
angular.module('Autofill-country', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('country', country);

function country($timeout, $q) {
var self = this;


if (countriesarrey == "undefined" || countriesarrey == null) { }
else { countrys(); }
// list of `country` value/display objects

function countrys() {

    self.countries = loadAll();
    self.selectedItem = null;
    self.searchTextcountry = null;
    self.querySearch = querySearch;

    // ******************************
    // Internal methods
    // ******************************

    /**
     * Search for countries... use $timeout to simulate
     * remote dataservice call.
     */
    function querySearch(query) {
        var results = query ? self.countries.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Build `countries` list of key/value pairs
     */

    function loadAll() {
        var allcountries = countriesarrey;
        console.log(countriesarrey);
        return allcountries.split(/, +/g).map(function (country) {
            return {
                value: country.toLowerCase(),
                display: country
            };
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create filter function for a query string
     */
    function createFilterFor(query) {
        var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

        return function filterFn(country) {
            return (country.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
        };

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to create some factory to fetch your data, that will have a method, returned promise. After promise will resolved, you can do what you want with fetched data.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('myFactory', function($http, $q, $timeout) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            // return $http.get(...);
        },
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function(myFactory) {
    this.getData = function() {
        myFactory.getData().then(function(response) {
            // use response.data here
        })
    }
})
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcpmsuxj/44/

Comment: I havent yet fully tried it but it looks really promise(ing). (Free puns for everybody I suppose), I am on the process of trying it. Thank you very much!